# Let $K \subseteq G$. Nec. and suff. cond. for that $\exists$ a normal subgr $H$ of $G$ s.t $exists$ transversal $I$ s.t $I \subseteq K$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I am trying to solve/understand the following question that I have come up with;

> Let $G$ be a group, and $K \subseteq G$ be given. What are the
>   necessary and sufficient condition for that there exists a normal
>   subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that we can find a transversal $I$ of $G/H$
>   with with $I = K$.

, or alternatively a more weak result that (as a starting point),

> Let $G$ be a group, and $K \subseteq G$ be given. Can we find an
>   equivalence relation on $G$ such that there exists a transversal I of
>   $G/K$ with $I \subseteq K$ ?

I have produced a couple of (really) trivial necessary conditions for the order of $H$ (if exists); however, I do not have any really progress in general, so what can we do ? Can you give me some starting point for even special type of groups ? is there any similar general/special result similar to this ([as in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964909/intuitive-explanation-for-let-i-g-be-the-group-of-all-inner-automorphisms-o))?

Comment: If I have understood the question correctly, then $K$ being nonempty is a necessary and sufficient condition, because we can take $H=G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt that is correct,  But i was looking for the nontrivial cases.

Comment: In that case you need to rephrase your question, because I have answered the question that you asked.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I have rephrased it.